# Is there a way to get e-readers to change endnotes into footnotes?

Tags: kindle, calibre, footnotes

I use Calibre on Linux and have a kindle (not sure the model but it has touchscreen and a built in light).

I'm wondering if there's a way to get these readers to move endnotes to the bottom of the relevant page (ie, to turn them into footnotes)? I find it to be a hassle to have to click away from the page i'm reading in order to pursue a footnote. In print versions of the ebooks I'm reading all the notes are footnotes rather than end-notes and it makes for a much more fluid experience.

Comment: Have you checked alternative reading apps for ebook readers such as koread?